# new child object in Core Data creating ″ghost″ parent?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, uiscrollview, nsmanagedobject

I have a parent entity called Notebook with a to Many relationship to the Page entity.
I have a scrollview displaying all my Notebook objects with their covers and I have a modal segue with view controller to add a new notebook object through a navigation button. When I use the save button in this add-notebook-viewcontroller everything goes well and I find myself with the new notebook along the others in my scrollview.

Now I tried to add the first page of the notebook by calling this method within the save button action method:

```
- (void) addFirstPage {
    Page *newPage = (Page *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Page" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]; 
    NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
    newPage.pageNumber = number;
    newPage.toNotebook = aNewNotebook;
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSURL *indexFileURL = [bundle URLForResource:@"index" withExtension:@"html"];
    newPage.page123andABC = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:indexFileURL usedEncoding:Nil error:Nil]; 
    NSError *error;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
        NSLog(@"Failed to add the first page: %@", [error domain]);
}
```

as you can see I set the new page′s notebook to be my new notebook (aNewNotebook).
At this point if I press the save button in the modal view I am presented with my scroll view that:

A) has added my Notebook cover as usual as the last notebook in the list (they are ordered by the creation date attribute).

B) I have an empty space at the beginning of the scroll view as if I had a second notebook there. If I add multiple notebooks there are as many void spaces in the beginning of the scrollview as notebooks.

I have tried to delete the notebook assigned to page before assigning my own (aNewNotebook) in case that one was created automatically, but it gives me the error that I am trying to delete nil.

Thus it′s like I am adding two notebooks (one without creationDate set- consistent with the fact that is appearing at the beginning of the scrollView and that indeed I set my creationDate only to aNewNotebook; the second being aNewNotebook).
But it′s also like I have only one because if I try to delete the unwanted one it says it does not exist.

Please help - it will be very appreciated :-)

UPDATE:

I tried to add two page objects at once in my addFirstPage method and I consistently find two new void notebook spaces in my scrollview.

Also, I used an NSLog to output the count of notebooks right after I add one page and I get a result of 2 notebooks- the one I just added and the one automatically added when I add new page object. So the count of notebooks is consistent  with what I see in the scrollView.

Any thoughts?

TEMPORARY SOLUTION THAT FEELS LIKE AN HACK:

in my addFirstPage method- after I create the page and before I save I added this code to delete the only notebook without a creationDate- that is the notebook automatically created by adding a new page:

```
 NSMutableArray *notebooksToDelete = [CoreDataHelper searchObjectsForEntity:@"Notebook" withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"creationDate == %@", nil] andSortKey:@"creationDate" andSortAscending:YES andContext:managedObjectContext];

Notebook *toDelete = [notebooksToDelete objectAtIndex:0];

[managedObjectContext deleteObject:toDelete];
```

I am really not satisfied with this solution so please feel free to suggest any improvement.

Comment: Is your object aNewNotebook an ivar of your view controller? Where do you get the value? Also, are you using multiple managed object contexts?

Comment: When I generated the files for my managed objects I was given a method that let me add a child to a parent [entity setParent: ]. Perhaps trying that instead of the dot notation?

Comment: Probably your logic in the scrollview creation is broken. Why would there be a blank space anyway? I guess if there was an actual notebook there would be a view for that notebook. So you should use some backgroundColor to figure out if there is a view or if you calculated the view origins wrong. And log the content of your context before and after your insert.

Comment: aNewNotebook is a property of the view controller typed as Notebook. I set a new object for Notebook entity to aNewNotebook in viewWillAppear. I am using only one managed object context. As far as the scrollview is concerned is not broken because if I do not add the code about the page it acts perfectly fine. This void spaces only happens if I try to add a new page object. I tried to use [entity setParent:] notation with no luck :-( –

Comment: There is no such thing as automatically created ghost objects. The problem lies in the display logic. Please share the code that displays the notebook cells, including anything you use to a) query for notebooks and b) update the view in response to objects inserted

Comment: then how do you explain that this happens only if I add the addFirstPage method? if I don′t all notebooks are displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same problem and found that the problem was caused by declaring a parent entity for my child entity in the data model.  Once I removed the parent entity the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

The only logical explanation from what has been exposed so far is that in your scroll view, you must be referencing the `Page` objects at some point to calculate the scroll view contents, rather than the `Notebook` objects. A quick text search in your view controller source file will reveal the culprit.

Make sure you log the number of pages of the said notebook before you exit the create notebook view controller. Also make sure you are not using the `Page` entity in your scroll view controller at all.